# Backup into physical file using CoreData

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, backup

I am going to use CoreData in one macOS application in order to manipulate about 100 MB that changes every second, the size should not increase significatively.
The relational nature of CoreData is exactly what I need.
I have to be very careful in order to not lose any data so I would like to create some physical file that I can store as backup.
Does CoreData has already an helper function to do this or have I got to write it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest built-in option is the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` method `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:`. It takes an existing persistent store and saves it in a new location. (Note that this method has nothing to do with migrating to newer versions of the data model). However, when this method completes, the old persistent store is removed from the persistent store coordinator and can't be used unless you re-add it.

Another option is to change the journal mode. Recent OS releases have used write-ahead logging, but the older "delete" mode is still supported. In that case you could simply copy the persistent store file, using `NSFileManager` methods. This is described in Apple's [Technical Q&A QA1809](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1809/_index.html). If you do that and you use Core Data's external binary support, you need to find and copy the directory used for the binary blobs.